# How do execute callback when state has been updated in redux?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Is it possible in redux to execute similar function to update state as it is in react? I mean to pass callback function as a parameter to action creator, which will execute after state update and inside this callback I will have possibility to access updated state? I've been searching a lot of different posts about this, but without any success. Why is it so hard to execute callback after state update in redux? In react this is very simple and we can simply do e.g.

`this.setState( { isLoading: false }, () => {
console.log(this.state.isLoading)
});`

Comment: A put effect followed by a select effect with redux-saga is one way of doing this.

Comment: @michal16511, If below answer worked for you, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) to dispatch actions synchronously. You can also use the lifecycle methods "componentDidUpdate" or "getDerivedStateFromProps" to check the props and state and execute other functions based on their current value.

Codesandbox to demonstrate using componentDidUpdate - https://codesandbox.io/s/simplest-redux-example-pwm7e